# How can I print a euro (€) symbol in Python?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm teaching myself Python using the command-line interpreter (v3.5 for Windows).

**All I want to do is output some text that includes the euro (€) symbol** which I understand to be code 80h (128 dec).

```
#!
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

mytext = 'Please pay \x8035.'
print(mytext)
```

It falls over on the last line:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x80' in position 11: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've done lots of googling (re encodings etc) and I've a rough idea why the print command fails. Tinkering with the above code shows that ASCII codes up to \x7f work fine, as one might expect.

But I can't figure out how to display the **€**, and I'm finding the information on encodings overwhelming and impenetrable. (Remember I'm just a noob!)

- I've tried prefixing the text string with *u* to create a unicode string in the first place.
- I've tried creating an intermediate object *outputtext = mytext.encode('utf-8')* but outputting this with *print* expands the string into an even more cryptic form: *b'Please pay \xc2\x8035.'*
- I've tried to find a different function instead of *print* to output this intermediate string, but nothing has worked yet.

Please can someone show me some code that **just works**, so I can study it and work backwards from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You can use Unicode Character Name

`\N{name}` is great way to print unicode character symbol.

Here is sample run....

```
>>> print "Please pay %s"%(u"\N{euro sign}")
Please pay €
>>> print "Please pay %s"%(u"\N{dollar sign}")
Please pay $
>>> print "Please pay %s"%(u"\N{rupee sign}")
Please pay ₨
>>> print "Please pay %s"%(u"\N{pound sign}")
Please pay £
```

Answer (score 9):

Here are four ways of printing a string with the Euro symbol in Python 3.x, in increasing order of obscurity.

**1. Direct input**

Use your keyboard to enter the symbol, or copy and paste it from somewhere else:

```py
mytext = "Please pay €35."
print(mytext)
```

**2. Use Unicode glyph number**

Look up the Unicode glyph number, for example from the very useful page http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/, and use that code in your string:

```py
mytext = "Please pay \u20ac35."
print(mytext)
```

**3. Use glyph name**

You can use [`lookup()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unicodedata.html) from the `unicodedata` module to access Unicode glyphs by name. Again http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/ will help you find the glyph name:

```py
import unicodedata

mytext = "Please pay {}35.".format(unicodedata.lookup("EURO SIGN"))
print(mytext)
```

**4. Use Windows-1252 codepage**

If you really want to use the `\x80` byte code, you can do that, because it represents the Euro symbol in the Windows-1252 codepage. What you need to do is first create a byte string containing that byte code, and then decoding that byte string so that the byte code is translated to the Euro symbol entry in the Windows-1252 codepage:

```py
mytext = b"Please pay \x8035.".decode("windows-1252")
print(mytext)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
mytext = 'Please pay \u20ac.'
print(mytext)
```

... based on [Unicode Character 'EURO SIGN'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm).

But if the character can be represented in the script's character encoding, then there is no reason why you shouldn't write:

```
mytext = 'Please pay €.'
```

Answer (score 3):

Euro is encoded as `80h` (`0x80`) in the `windows-1252` charset and you must tell Python that:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

mytext = b'Please pay \x8035.'.decode('windows-1252')
print(mytext)
```

You could also write the real euro character directly in the source code or use its representation, as others said, using the correct encoding (`utf-8`):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

mytext = u'Please pay \u20ac35.'
print(mytext)
```

... or ...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

mytext = 'Please pay €35.'
print(mytext)
```

This code works both in Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.python-forum.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13995 :

This is behavior of python 2,Python 3 does not do this.

Python 2.7:

```
>>> s = "€"
>>> s
'\xe2\x82\xac'
>>> print s
â‚¬
>>> s = u"€"
>>> s
u'\u20ac'
>>> print s
€
>>> print('\xe2\x82\xac'.decode('utf8'))
€
```

Python 3.4

```
>>> s = '€'
>>> s
'€'
>>> print(s)
€
>>> 
>>> print(repr(s))
'€'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, you can simply copy and paste the € character directly into a UTF-8 encoded text file (no need for codes):

```
mytext = 'Please pay €.'
print(mytext)
```