# Encoding error that only shows in the Interactive Window

Tags: python-3.x

### Summary

I am making a program in python, and I've finished it, ran it in shell and it worked perfectly. However when I run the program in the Interactive Window, it produces an error while in the idle window, it doesn't.

### Crash information

Picture of the error before the window crashes:

[image: Error Before crash]

```
### COFFEE SHOP APP ###
# IMPORTS
from Motto import ourMotto 
import time 
import os 
import sys 
# MAIN CODE
def CoffeeShopApp(): 
    # VARIABLES
    orderCost = 0 
    smallCost = 2.00 
    mediumCost = 3.50 
    largeCost = 4.75 
    spicyCost = 5.25 
    coffeeInput = False 
    sugarCost = 0.05 
    sugarInput = False 
    syrupCost = 0.50 
    syrupInput = False 
    print("Welcome to the Michael the Moose Coffee App - Where the price is right") 
    print("You've tried BartSucks, and it sucks so now try the best")
    print("We will guide you through the ordering process and our amazing Barista 'Michelle' in Barcelona will then serve you\n") 
    print("And our amazing Barista 'Michelle' in Barcelona will then serve you\n") 
    while coffeeInput == False:
        tempSize = input( 
        """
                    What size would you like your coffee?
        Small - 2€, Medium - 3.50€, Large - 4.75€  or Spicy - 5.25€
        """
        )
        tempSize = tempSize.title() 
        if tempSize == "Small": 
            coffeeSize = "Small" 
            coffeeInput = True 
            orderCost = (orderCost + smallCost) 
        elif tempSize == "Medium": 
            coffeeSize = "Medium" 
            coffeeInput = True 
            orderCost = (orderCost + mediumCost)
        elif tempSize == "Large":
            coffeeSize = "Large"
            coffeeInput = True 
            orderCost = (orderCost + largeCost)
        elif tempSize == "Spicy":
            coffeeSize = "Spicy"
            coffeeInput = True 
            orderCost = (orderCost + spicyCost)
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid size")
            coffeeInput = False
            time.sleep(0.5)

    print()
    orderCost = str(orderCost)
    print("Ok, currently your order costs "+orderCost+"€")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print()

    while sugarInput == False:
        tempSugar = int(input(
        """
                How many sugars would you like added to your coffee?
        1 sugar - 0.05€, 2 sugars - 0.10€, 3 sugars - 0.15€, 4 sugars - 0.20€: 
        """
        ))
        if isinstance(tempSugar, int):
            if tempSugar > 4:
                print("Please enter a valid number of sugars")
                sugarInput = False
                time.sleep(0.5)
            else:
                orderCost = float(orderCost)
                orderCost = (orderCost + (tempSugar * sugarCost))
                sugarInput = True
        else:
            print("Please enter a number")

    print()
    orderCost=str(orderCost)
    print("Ok, currently your order costs "+orderCost+"€")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print()

    while syrupInput == False:
        tempSyrup = input(
        """
                       Would you like syrup? (0.50€): 
        """)
        tempSyrup = tempSyrup.title()
        if tempSyrup == "Yes":
            syrupInput = True
        elif tempSyrup == "No":
            syrupInput = True
        else:
            print("Please enter either yes/no")
            time.sleep(0.5)

    orderCost = str(orderCost)
    print("Alright, your final order cost comes up to: "+orderCost+"€")
    name = input("Please enter your name and our barista Michelle will get straight to work on your coffee: ")
    name = name.upper()

    tempSugar = str(tempSugar)
    orderCost = str(orderCost)
    lines = ['Here is your new order: It is size: '+tempSize+'',
            'There are '+tempSugar+' sugars to be put in the coffee',
            'and they have said '+tempSyrup+' to having syrup.',
            'Their name is '+name+,
            'It will cost: '+orderCost+'€',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            ourMotto]
    with open('MichelleMooseCoffeeOrders.txt', 'w') as MMC:
        for l in lines:
            MMC.write(l + '\n')

    MMC.close()

    print(
    """
                           Your order has been proccessed
            Please come and collect your order at the shop within the hour,
                          or your order will be incinerated
    """
    )
    input("Press ENTER to exit the app")
    if mode == 'Interactive' or mode == 'I':
        os.system('cls')

mode = input("Are you in shell/interactive mode?")
mode = mode.title()
if mode == 'Interactive' or mode == 'I':
    os.system('cls')

input("Slide left to sign in")
if mode == 'Interactive' or mode == 'I':
    os.system('cls')

appreal = False
while appreal == False:
    app = input(
    """
                     What app would you like to use?
                Coffee Shop, (more coming sometime soon)
    """
    )
    app = app.title()
    if app == 'Coffee Shop' or app == 'Cs':
        if mode == 'Interactive' or mode == 'I':
            os.system('cls')
        CoffeeShopApp()
    elif app == '':
        pass
```

Line 169 is a call for a subroutine

Line 30 is an end of a print shaped like this:

```
print(
"""
*text here*
"""
)
```

And the line 12 seems to refer to a program in the python files.
In the program it imports a variable from a python program in the same location as this question.

### Related Files

The imported file is this:

```
ourMotto = ('You have been playing for over an hour. Please do not forget to take a break.')
```

It writes to a text file in the same file location named:

MichelleMooseCoffeeOrders

If you need me to add any more information about the program or help me format this question, then leave a comment. (I'm new to stack overflow and am still learning how to format questions so feedback helps)

error code after utf-8 encoding:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File"Z:\Year9\LessonWork\I.C.T\ComputerScience(Wednesday)\Programming\CoffeeShopApp\CoffeeShopApp.p, line 169, in <module>
      CoffeeShopApp
    File"Z:\Year9\LessonWork\I.C.T\ComputerScience(Wednesday)\Programming\CoffeeShopApp\CoffeeShopApp.py", line 30, in CoffeeShopApp
      """
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\encoding\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmaps_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' in position 76:P character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Get rid of the euro sign and try again!

Comment: I'll try it and  get back to you after I've tried it

Comment: I have removed all euro signs and it gives the same error

Comment: Alternatively, you can try adding this: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of your code without getting rid of the euro sign! See [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) link for more info on what the above line means.

Comment: In case if utf-8 doesn't work, try `# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-` instead of the utf-8 one.

Comment: What error are you getting after removing the euro signs?

Comment: The same error as before -- `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` doesn't work so I'll try latin-1

Comment: Include everything in the grey box, **even the hash sign**.

Comment: I've tried `# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-` and it gives the same error as before in the interactive window    I have included the # sign btw

Comment: Paste the error you get after removing the euro sign.

Comment: With or without the encoding?

Comment: With the encoding.

Comment: I have added it to the end of the question. Sorry if the spacing is incorrect as i had to copy it from a picture that was gotten from a screenshot from the interactive window before it crashed

Comment: The euro sign is still there somewhere! At the last line of the stack trace (error text) you see `'\u20ac'` somewhere right? That's the Euro sign character.

Comment: Try `# -*- coding: utf-16 -*-` as a last resort!

Comment: I was just removing ones in the bit that was writing to the text file. I'll get rid of ALL euro signs.

Comment: Try **utf-16** first, please!

Comment: It works! But is there a way to keep it in without it giving an error? Oh sorry I just saw that you said to do the utf-16 first. I'll put one back in and try the encoding

Comment: Added 1 euro back into the code, still gives an error with the utf-16 encoding

Comment: That's what I think these encoding declarations will do, they let you keep those weird signs without any error but, I think I am missing something. Can you E-mail me the code?

Comment: What's your email address?

Comment: Wait a bit, let me check some internet resources first! btw it's ubdussamad @ google mail .

Comment: email me first at: '15CWhitehead@roydshall.org' when you've looked at some internet resources

Comment: Okay, I think I have it, where ever you have a print or string declaration which has a euro sign just attach `.encode("utf-8")` at the back of it. Like `print("Hello world".encode("utf-8"))` or `string = 'Hello world".encode("utf-8")`

Comment: For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935857/how-can-i-print-a-euro-%E2%82%AC-symbol-in-python).

Comment: What about with arrays?

Comment: What do you mean by array? What does an array has to do with encoding problem?

Comment: I have an array and in one of the values it has a euro sign at the end of it. What do it do for the encode here?

Comment: Ran it, when it came to the first place with euros with my encoding it printed this: b'\n                    What size would you like your coffee?\n        Small - 2\xe2\x82\xac, Medium - 3.50\xe2\x82\xac, Large - 4.75\xe2\x82\xac, or Spicy - 5.25\xe2\x82\xac\n        '

Comment: Hahaha, My apologies for the crappy encoded output. Let me see if someone more experienced than me can help!

Comment: Ok. thanks for trying to fix my mess of a program :)

Comment: Send me your code anyway, I've mailed your account!